# How do you know when the client is connected to the server?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, ubuntu

From the below code, what code do i need to add in order to know when has the client connected to the server?
Thanks! :D

```
int sd, rc;
socklen_t cliLen;
struct sockaddr_in cliAddr, servAddr;
char* argv = (char*) arg;

/* socket creation */
sd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(sd<0) 
{
    printf("%s: cannot open socket \n",argv);
    //   exit(1);
}

/* bind local server port */
servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servAddr.sin_port = htons(LOCAL_SERVER_PORT);
rc = bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr,sizeof(servAddr));
if(rc<0) 
{
    printf("%s: cannot bind port number %d \n",
    argv, LOCAL_SERVER_PORT);
    //    exit(1);
}

printf("%s: waiting for data on port UDP %u\n",argv,LOCAL_SERVER_PORT);

while(1)
{
    /* init buffer */
    memset(msg,0x0,MAX_MSG);


    /* receive message */
    n = recvfrom(sd, msg, MAX_MSG, 0,(struct sockaddr *) cliAddr,sizeof(cliAddr));
}
```

---

Since this is done through UDP(connectionless), we are unable to know when the client has connected. Is there a way for us to know who sent the data?

Comment: UDP is connectionless; no one ever "connects". You know you have data when ... you get data.

Comment: Technically, a "connection()" only occurs with streams (after the 3-way TCP handshake succeeds and your server's "accept()" gives you a new socket).  *None* of this happens with datagrams.  Your code looks fine as-is.

Comment: @BrianRoach thanks for the reply!, so is there any way to identify who sent the data to the server? As i would need to do a diffie-hellman protocol to exchange keys and then encrypt data when sending to the user.

Comment: @paulsm4, well, when you use TCP, you have your three-way handshake to establish connection. So you can say that if that succeeds, the connection is established.

Comment: @dupdupdup - You can get the client IP from the `struct sockaddr` you're passing in (cliAddr) - it gets filled in when data is received. Other than that you would need the data being sent to also contain identifier info.

Comment: @BrianRoach Able to give an example of how to use it? i did it this way and it came out an address space 0x1203811blablabla

For Example : std::cout << (struct sockaddr *) cliAddr << std::endl

Answer (score 3):

You are using `SOCK_DGRAM` which indicates a UDP socket.

UDP is not like TCP, there is no "connection" really, you just send packages of data and *hope* they reach the target.

However, if you want to indicate the fact of receiving something, you could add

```
printf("Recieved data");
```

after

```
 n = recvfrom(sd, msg, MAX_MSG, 0,(struct sockaddr *) cliAddr,sizeof(cliAddr));
```